# Is there any way to get more workers?

Tags: tiny-tower-vegas

I find I have lots of money to build floors, and I have bux out the wazoo for upgrades and stuff, but I am lacking in people to actually work at my businesses.

So far it just seems like I have to watch and wait for a worker to arrive in the lobby, but is there any other way I can get workers?

Answer (score 2):

No as mentioned in the other answer, you have to wait. My best advice is always keep one of the 5 slots open when you need workers, use level 9s when appropriate, and switch them out for the first dream job applicant you can. If you have a difference in points by 1 or 2 you can consider firing the first bitizen and taking a small decrease for a chip.

Not really worth it long term but it helps if that is your goal. If there is any increase in their performance you should instantly fire whoever holds the position for the more qualified applicant. I would take a level 0 dream versus a level 9 with a dream not befitting the employment I gave them.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the game, **no.**   If you click a blank slot in the lobby (in hopes of buying a new applicant), this does not do anything.

Currently (V.1.0.1), you can only get applicants by waiting for them to show up in the lobby.

You can however click on the lobby and click `quick stock` to fully stock one floor at the cost of a few coins and bux.

Comment: Quick stock actually stocks the ENTIRE TOWER, so if you have a lot of floors, it's not just a few coins or bux. It can be a lot!

Answer (score -2):

Yes. If you tape each of the slots in the lobby an applicant will show up.